# Запуск процесса в BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, потоки-данных, backgroundworker

Не могу запустить процесс (Process.Start()) в BackgroundWorker (т.е. когда он уже выолняет фоновый процесс).

Эксепшенов никаких нет, пробовал запускать другие exe-файлы - ничего не работает. Один из них просто должен был создать левый файл, чтобы узнать что процесс действительно был запущен, но этого не происходило. Т.е. всё гворит о том, что как-будто exe-шник вообще не запускался.

Код:

```
Process p1 = new Process();
p1.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
p1.StartInfo.FileName = @"f:\exe.exe";
p1.Start();
p1.WaitForExit();
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: ни одного ответа :(
это я умею - вопросики задавать)

Comment: Варианты:
1. Поставить бряк или MessageBox.show в районе p1.Start(); и посмотреть приходит ли туда.
2. Отказаться от BackgroundWorker и сделать кусок стандартным потоком.

Comment: пробовал 1 - всё хорошо, доходит, но не запускается
2 - уже начал писать до Вашего коммента :)

Comment: второй вариант тоже не работает

Comment: хм...

Претензий к коду особых нету.

Не генерятся ли какие-нибудь исключения ну может прав не хватает, файлик какой-то не находит?

Попробуйте в запускаемый процесс сделать sleep секунд на 10-15, чтоб визуально отловить через таск-менеджер.

Попробуйте запустить этот!! же код в основном потоке.
И попроверяйте на всякие оплошности - код стандартен как двери - вряд ли тут ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка, оказывается, была в том, что не был указан параметр WorkingDirectory, поэтому и файл, свидетельствующий о запуске программы создавался не в том же месте, где лежит exe-шник. Вот какая досадная мелочь, на которой можно "лохануться" :)

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно использую статический метод `Process.Start(string fileName, string arguments)`

Никогда не было проблем. Может, нестатический не для этого?